Persistent ripple at the buck converter output
I developed a half-bridge buck converter, I did all the steps, from the converter calculations, such as accommodating the copper in the appropriate ferrite core, wire gauge diameter, etc., my project was for a buck converter operating at 50 kHz to vary the output voltage from 12-22 V with an input of 24 V with a maximum current of 3 A.
I used the gate driver IR2104 + MOSFET's IRF840 in the circuit, the oscillation signal is generated by an ESP32 (for prototyping purposes), I calculated the minimum output capacitance in order to filter the ripple so that my ripple did not exceed 1% at maximum current. I placed a much larger capacitor than calculated to have a good clearance... But this strange ripple (which obviously has the same frequency as my gate driver's switching frequency, as seen in the oscilloscope images below) continues to torment me. I can't remove it, I know that breadboard mounting is not suitable due to ground loops, parasitic inductances, etc., etc., but should this ripple be so evident, even with these assembly characteristics?
I am new to the development of switching sources in power electronics, I only used to buy the most suitable commercial source and was ready to assemble the other circuits. I think I lack the insights of someone who already has experience in the field of power electronics.
P.S: I made a small mistake in the schematic, the IR2104 power is 12 V, which comes from the 7812 linear regulator. In the schematic, I made this little confusion and put the IR2104 power at 24 V
Below we have images showing:
The developed circuit diagram.
Images of the circuit assembled on a breadboard.
Oscilloscope with AC coupling showing output ripple when I have a duty cycle of 10% and a load of 30 mA.
Oscilloscope with AC coupling showing output ripple when I have 90% duty cycle and 500 mA load.





Looks like inductance of your long wires before the output capacitor

If i am correct, you need to add ceramic capacitor (1-10 uF) and try to use a wider or shorter wire (or both).

Breadboard and scope ground lead likely to be huge contributors. Design a proper PCB with good decoupling and layout of the critical high dI/dt paths and incorporate test points that allow the use of the short scope ground spring.

Does this answer your question? Gate and Drain ringing on a highside MOSFET Driver

Breadboard and discrete switchmode converters are mutually exclusive. You need to design a PCB for it with ground plane.
